# Displaying contents on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am designing my first web page.

I have an image as a background and a menu tab.

When i click an option on the tab,i want the image in the background to fade out and the respective contents of the tab to be loaded.

I am new to web designing.
I searched it on Google and saw many methods for it like using ajax. 
But i am confused with which method to use.
I do not have a database.

Comment: You can simply use jquery. It the perfect solution for this situation.

Comment: i have seen jquery also. but i would like to know whether it would be the best method.

Comment: It is the perfect method.

Comment: look for "single page websites", "jquery ajax" :)

Comment: @Alex there is no need for ajax here.

Comment: yes, there is. read the OPs text: "contents of the tab to be loaded". he may mean simply to fade them in, but it can also mean to load them via ajax, doesnt it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fading stuff in and out jQuery is your friend.

Look at the aptly named [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) methods.

There are some examples on the doc pages and here's [a tutorial](http://kaidez.com/javascript-for-loop-creates-jquery-fade/) to get you started.